# mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported

Tags: mount, nfs

Need troubleshooting help with NFS mounts. I have dir1 and dir2 and, as far as I can tell, all NFS-related settings and permissions are the same for both of these directories.

Both directories mount correctly on most clients. But on workstation 192.168.1.14, only dir1 will mount. dir2 fails to mount as shown below. I cannot understand why.

I believe the output below provides the needed info. Please let me know if I need to post additional output.

### File server:

```
/etc/exports:
#workstation=192.168.1.14
/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir1 192.168.1.14(rw,sync,subtree_check,nohide)
/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir2 192.168.1.14(rw,sync,subtree_check,nohide)

exporting 192.168.1.10:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir1
exporting 192.168.1.12:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir1
exporting 192.168.1.14:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir1
exporting 192.168.1.10:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir2
exporting 192.168.1.12:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir2
exporting 192.168.1.14:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir2

[root@fileserver Internal]# ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 user1 staff 4096 Feb 22 23:20 .
drwxr-x--x  32 user1 staff 4096 Apr 22 22:29 ..
drwxrws--x+  2 user1 staff 4096 May 29 14:34 dir2
drwxrwx--x+  4 user1 staff 4096 May 30 20:47 dir1
```

### Client machine (workstation):

```
/etc/fstab
fileserver:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir1 /home/staffcom/Internal/dir1 nfs4 auto,noatime        0 0
fileserver:/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir2 /home/staffcom/Internal/dir2 nfs4 auto,noatime        0 0

[root@workstation Internal]# ls -la
total 0
drwxrws--- 1 user3 staff  28 May 30 22:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 user3 staff 104 Mar 28 19:15 ..
drwxrws--x 1 root     staff   0 May 30 22:51 dir2
drwxrws--x 1 root     staff   0 May 30 22:50 dir1


[root@workstation Internal]# showmount -e fileserver | grep "Internal/dir2"
/export/home/staffcom/Internal/dir2                      192.168.1.10,192.168.1.12,192.168.1.14
```

RESULT: dir2 fails to mount:

```
[root@workstation Internal]# mount /home/staffcom/Internal/dir2/
mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported
```

RESULT: dir1 successfully mounted:

```
[root@workstation Internal]# mount /home/staffcom/Internal/dir1/
[root@workstation Internal]#
```

Checking mount with verbose output shows more clues:

```
[root@workstation Internal]# mount -v /home/staffcom/Internal/dir2/
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Tue May 30 23:17:32 2017
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.14'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.1'
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs4: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs4: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program/version mismatch
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs4: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot UDP port 2049
mount.nfs4: portmap query failed: RPC: Program/version mismatch
mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported
```

Comment: The only difference is the permissions on `dir1` and `dir2` on the server.  `dir2` has `g=s` while `dir1` has `g=x`.  I'm not turning this into an answer since I have no way of testing if this is the problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for your comment. I ended up taking the one problematic client machine out of service. However, I saved it in the same state. Therefore, I can put it back in service and do some troubleshooting when I get time. I may try that in the next month or so.